# SMACK: how do I listen for user availability status changes?

Tags: smack, asmack

How do I subscribe to listen to user availability status changes in SMACK?

To get the availability status for a user I use the following:

```
XMPPConnection.getRoster().getPresence(name).isAvailable();
```

But how can I subscribe so I receive some notifications whenever the status changes? (So I don't have to poll).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[You set up a listener for Roster and Presence changes](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/roster.html).

Comment: I tries your link, but the listener wont call

Comment: five years later your answer is still useful

Answer (score 4):

this code may help you :

```
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
                // Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {}
                public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
                public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
                public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                    System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom() + " " + presence);
                }
                @Override
                public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
            // Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {}
            public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
            public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
            public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {

                Log.e(TAG, presence.getStatus());
                    Log.e(TAG,presence.getFrom());
                    Log.e(TAG, presence.getLanguage());
                    Log.e(TAG,presence.getDefaultLanguage());
                    Log.e(TAG, presence.getType().toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```